# I purged the Libreoffice-writer app from the system. Why do i still see files with the name 'libreoffice' on my system?

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, software-uninstall

So i just got rid of Libreoffice writer app from my system through the terminal with the purge command. To make sure i don't leave behind any files related to libre-office i also ran the autoremove command after it. Still when i run 'apt list --installed' (photo attached) i also see some files with the name 'libreoffice'. Why is that? Are those configuration files ? If so, the purge command is supposed to get rid of the configurations too, isn't it? How do i get rid of these files assuming they are just left-overs from the libreoffice-writer app i had uninstalled before.

Related info - I've never installed anything related to libreoffice on my system before.Also i never installed the whole libreoffice suit. I only installed the libreoffice-writer app from Ubuntu's software app.

['apt list --installed' result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx28M.png)

Comment: I did not install the whole suite. I only installed the libreoffice writer app from the ubuntu software center app. How do i get rid of these lingering 'components' if they serve no purpose being on my system?

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the purpose of both autoremove and purge. Neither "forces" removal of a package tree. If you investigate, you will see that LibreOffice Math is required by some other element of your system -- usually the desktop metapackage. Therefore, it's not orphaned. Therefore it's not eligible for autoremoval. In turn, everything that Math depends upon is also ineligible for autoremoval.

Comment: Unless they have changed, libreoffice suite is included when you install Ubuntu.  Usually do not need to install the 'writer' app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To purge libreoffice completely you have to remove all its packages by

```
sudo apt-get purge '*libreoffice*' --autoremove
```

Comment: What are the astericks around 'libreoffice' is for ?

Comment: They will remove all ocurrencies including `libreoffice` word, asterisks mean any symbol. If unsure try to simulate this command first `apt-get purge '*libreoffice*' --autoremove --simulate` .